# xubuntu 12.04 can't change desktop background/wallpaper permanently

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, desktop-background

If I change the desktop background (wallpaper) via right-click on desktop => desktop settings => single image, and select another background image from the list, or add a photo of my own (via the "+" symbol), I can actually change the background image, but after logging out or restarting, the wallpaper is always reset to the original xubuntu 12.04 background.

So, basically, I can't find a way to permanently change the desktop background.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, after some more research I have found out that this should actually a Xubuntu bug. My solution: I installed "Wallch". Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way Xfce is built, if you change settings and do not save session, the changes are not saved. It is not automatic. Menu -> Log out -> save session must be checked.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem but in Ubuntu 14.04.3: right-click on desktop>change desktop settings>add own image using <kbd>+</kbd> and "span" it across my two monitors. After logging out, then logging in again, I saw that the background was saved but not after restarting the computer.

I'm new in using Ubuntu but somehow know a bit about Linux and was able to set my first Ubuntu install yesterday (after deciding to leave Windows).

**So, here's my guess:** my wallpaper is not being found when I login because the *image is in an internal hard disk drive that is probably not mounted* upon login.

I copied my wallpaper from the unmounted HDD to somewhere inside my home folder (e.g. `~\Pictures\wallpapers\image.jpg`) and set this image as my desktop background, and my problem was solved.

I hope this helps someone similar to my case. This is my first time posting in Ask Ubuntu, so I hope I'm not violating some rules such as necromancy. ^_^